# JApplet error that I can't seem to fix

Tags: java, web, applet, japplet, invocationtargetexception

I am getting an annoying error for my Java applet. I am new to applets so please note that I am not that experienced with this at all.

I have an HTML file labelled as index.html with the following code:

```html
    <HTML>   
    <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Applet JAR Example
        </TITLE>
    </HEAD>  
    <BODY> 
        <CENTER>
            <B>Are YOU ready to dance??
            </B>
            <BR>
                <BR>

                <APPLET CODE="shawn/Main.class" ARCHIVE="lol.jar"
                        WIDTH=400      
                HEIGHT=300>    
</APPLET>   
</CENTER>
</BODY>  
</HTML>
```

In the same directory, I have a Jar file labelled as lol.jar with the following code:

```
package shawn;

import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JApplet implements Serializable {

        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("hey.gif");

        @Override
        public void init(){
            playSound();
        }

       @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)    {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void playSound(){
        AudioClip ac = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "hey.wav");
        ac.play();
    }
}
```

Inside that same directory, I have two files labelled as hey.wav, and hey.gif.

When I execute the page the applet fails to load, outputting only the message `Error. Click for details`. When I click, it says:

> RuntimeException

followed by...

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Everything works when I run it in Eclipse, but it only does this when I export it. I`ll add more details if needed.

Comment: Could you post the _full_ stacktrace. Exception classes ain't much help.

Comment: There is no other stacktrace, even if I click on Details it just returns a console with essential help commands, but nothing to do with the code at all.

Comment: You've got a bug in your applet's code. What it is, I've no idea since we can't see that code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW:- Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definite problem in the applet is:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("hey.gif");
```

If you look at the JavaDocs for [`getImage(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.lang.String%29) it states:

> Returns an image which gets pixel data from the specified **file**, whose format can be either GIF, JPEG or PNG. The underlying toolkit attempts to resolve multiple requests with the same filename to the same returned Image.

The highlight of **file** was by my choice.  Applets and files are rarely used together, and it is not appropriate for this situation.  Instead the `Image` must be accessed by `URL`.

Applet offers instead [`Applet.getImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL%29) & [`getImage(URL,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29).  The 2nd is particularly handy when we need to form an `URL` relative to the code base or document base.

If the image is located in the same directory as the HTML, it might be loaded using something along the lines of:

```
Image img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "hey.gif");
```